# To Display All comments for a selected Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating a forum which have some what similar look as this!
A user can ask a Question and can get answer for that from other users.

I have two different table Question{id(pk), Question} and Answer{id(pk), ans, Qid(fk)}

Also i have created Controller for this
It contain Index,create,details
in side Index ,i have inserted as follows:

```
using (var _db = new Model1Container())
        {
           Question q = _db.Questions.Find(id);
            return View(q);
        }
```

inside the view i have a link called show which will show all the comments related to that particular question.....

but I'm not able to do this...i have tried:

```
        using (var _db = new Model1Container())
        {
            var a = (from m in _db.Answers
                     where m.QuestionQId == id
                     select m);

            return View(a);
        }
```

but it is not working...i am using Entity framework

please help me out!!!

Comment: What is not working? You get an error or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
select m);
```

To

```
 using (var _db = new Model1Container())
        {
            var a = (from m in _db.Answers
                     where m.QuestionQId == id
                     select m).ToList();

            return View(a);
        }
```

To force execution now. Otherwise execution of the query can happen outside the scope of your _db variable.